# Saving stdout.read() adds \n

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am saving the output of stdout in Python 3 like this...

```
filename = stdout.read()
print (repr(filename))
```

The resulting filename string has a \n at the end of it.  I know I can process this after the event and strip them but is there a way of grabbing stdout.read without the new line?

Comment: No, you're stuck with stripping it afterwards.

Comment: the '\n' is a part of stdout ... so you are forced to strip it afterwards.

Comment: Thought as much, was worth checking though.  Regex the best way to strip do you think?

Comment: i'd probably use `filename = filename.strip()`

Comment: or just `stdout.read().strip()`

Comment: Did you mean `stdin.read()`? `stdout` is traditionally unreadable. If this really is `sys.stdin`, then `read` is a potentially bad idea because it will hang until the outer thing feeding data closes the pipe. `stdin.readline().strip()` is likely better.

Comment: You could also do `filename = input()`. It strips the newline for you... but does't strip any extraneous spaces.

Comment: It really helps to post running example code. Your code doesn't run because `stdout` isn't defined, leaving us guessing what `stdout` is supposed to be. Since `sys.stdout` would also raise an error, its even more puzzling. Its clear that you didn't run the code and you ended up posting a rather nonsensical question.

Answer (score 0):

### A Quick and dirty solution...

```
filename = stdout.read()
filename = filename.strip('\n')
print (repr(filename))
```

A *really* lazy solution, but it works.